# Checking room availability using codeigniter query

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter.
Now  I am developing a hotel room booking system. Now I am facing some issues in checking the availability of rooms while booking.

[image: Booking Tabele database stracture]

My Query for checking room availability

```
$cindt = $this->input->post('myCheckInDate');
$coutdt = $this->input->post('myCheckOutDate');
$roomid = $this->input->post('room');
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('booking');
$this->db->where("b_room", $roomid);
       $this->db->where('b_cin <= ',$cindt);
       $this->db->where('b_cout <= ',$cindt);
       $this->db->where('b_cout >= ',$coutdt);  
       $this->db->where('b_cin >= ',$coutdt);       
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $nn=$query->result_array(); 
                        //print_r($nn); exit();

    if($nn){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('yes', 'Rooms is not Available');
                    redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
                }
```

Comment: What's the issue are you not getting desired results?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile yes not getting desired results.

Comment: Where is total rooms?

Comment: @Nikhil can you show us your all POST values before select statement? I think your date format is not matching with DB Column format

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055270/hotel-room-booking-reservation?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

```
$cindt = $this->input->post('myCheckInDate');
$coutdt = $this->input->post('myCheckOutDate');
$roomid = $this->input->post('room');

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('b_cin >=', $cindt);
    $this->db->where('b_cout <=', $coutdt);
    $this->db->where('b_room', $roomid);
    $this->db->from('booking');
    $nn = $this->db->get()->result();

  if($nn > 0){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('yes', 'Rooms is not Available');
                    redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
                }
```